# AS3 AIR - NativeWindow pop-up box

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, nativewindow

In my AIR application, when a user creates a new project I want a pop-up box to appear where they can enter their project's name in. I understand how this is doable by making my own type of pop-up box, but is there a way to do this using NativeWindows? That is, can I make a window using the system chrome appear which contains a text field and a button?

I'm using Flex 4 and AIR 2.7 in FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. When creating a new NativeWindow you can add and remove children to its stage. So you could add your class / components to the new window and listen to their events.

```
// create NativeWindowInitOptions
var windowInitOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
windowInitOptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
windowInitOptions.minimizable = true;
windowInitOptions.resizable = false;
windowInitOptions.maximizable = false;
windowInitOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
windowInitOptions.transparent = false;

// create new NativeWindow
var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(windowInitOptions);

// create your class
var popupBox:Sprite = new Sprite();

// resize
newWindow.width = popupBox.width;
newWindow.height = popupBox.height;

// add
newWindow.stage.addChild(popupBox);

// configure
popupBox.addEventListener(YourCustomEvent.CONFIRM, onPopupConfirm);

// for a popup it might be nice to have it activated and on top
newWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
newWindow.activate();
```

Within the onPopupConfirm function you can close the Window and cleanup references. (Event.CLOSING on the NativeWindow, could come in handy for catching alt+F4 closing and such)

Comment: Sweet, thanks mate. I was thinking of trying something like this myself but I just thought to ask anyway. Bit inexperienced with making NativeWindows. Keep up the good work.